# how to setup failover network with docker on synology

Tags: docker, cloudflare, containers, synology

I have one synology nas with 2 nic and I have two different internet connect from 2 different ISP. and I am using cloudflare zero trust service in my docker on synology.

that nas server nics connect to the same router. and I setup my router to give 2 external IP address to my nas.

how can I restart or update my cloudflare docker container when first internet down and switch to second internet connection.

P.S. I test it with bridge network on my docker container and it works. it is updating cloudflare with my active internet connection. But I cannot reach my nas via web because of that bridge network setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two public IP endpoint you should setup the host to listen on remote control port (ssh or web ?) on both IP. Then you should be able to access the 2nd one with no access to the first one.
Just be careful of the default routes. Maybe you need to setup keepalive and have you main IP floating between the two nics instead of failure.
Also an other lead would be to use a reverseproxy (like HAproxy) in front to do the failover between the two ISP backends.

Comment: so how can I configure my docker settings about to use both internet with failover?

Comment: It depends of you docker setup and how docker proxy port wrapping is done.There not only solution as said in my answer : you can set the "failover" at different levels, try to pick the most efficient in your context.